# Generated videos not recognizable in VLC

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I generated my first video in Blender today. I folowed Paul Caggeggis instructions in "Introduction to Video Editing in Blender Part 01" on youtube.
I have the latest Blender on an OpenSuse 15.
When I generate the videos and open them I get only a unrecognizable ( screenshot below) video ( mov and mp4)  or black ( .dvd ) in VLC.
The original MP4 videos I merged in this video are MP4 and can be shown in VLC ( they have PAL resolution ).

Does anyone have a solution to my beginners question

Thank you very much
Andreas
[image]

Comment: seeing your output and encoding settings will help to understand the trouble.

Comment: Yeah, we're definitely not going to spend our time searching a tutorial (which you could have posted the link here) and watch through 35min of video in order to know what you did. Please show us more.